# I can`t change the font size and the font style for my website`s home page

Tags: html, css, fonts

I want to change my font size, color and style.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div id="content">

        <center><h1>Learn</h1></center>

    </div>
```

.. And my CSS code:

```
 #content{
margin: 70px 0;
background: none;
padding: 60px;
clear: both;
padding: 195px;
font-style: verdana;
font-color:white;

}
```

Comment: You are using the incorrect css properties. You're looking for "font-family" and just "color". I suggest using a reference for the css properties as you are learning: 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_color.asp

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS rule should be

```
#content{
  margin: 70px 0;
  background: none;
  padding: 60px;
  clear: both;
  padding: 195px;
  font-family: Verdana sans-serif; /* changed */
  color:white; /* changed */
}
```

However, with these settings you are going to have white text on white background -> this text will be invisible, so you should change that "color" setting

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like there is a H1 definition that overwrites your rules for content. Check for a h1 color/size/font definition anywhere in your code. Since it is more specific than content, it will overwrite it.

Try to set your rules in `#content h1 {}`. It should work.

Comment: You are a life saver !! Thank you

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense with your comment to it. Has this solved your issue? Because as others have correctly answered, your initial CSS is invalid.

Comment: JoughDrak : Glad it helped. If this solved your problem could you click on the checkmark to select that answer as the valid one ?
Also as @Lee stated, correct your css property as the other answer stated. They get my upvote !